# Unable to overwrite Contact Form in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, magento-2.0, contact-us

I'm trying to overwrite contact form but it's unable to overriding. For this I have followed below steps.

Step 1) **app/code/Learning/Contact/composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "learning/contact",
  "description": "contact",
  "require": {
      "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
      "magento/framework": "100.0.*",
      "magento/module-ui": "100.0.*",
      "magento/module-config": "100.0.*"
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
  "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Learning\\Contact\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Step 2) **app/code/Learning/Contact/registration.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Learning_Contact',
    __DIR__
);
```

Step 3) **app/code/Learning/Contact/etc/module.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Learning_Contact" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Contact"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Step 4) **app/code/Learning/Contact/view/frontend/layout/contact_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Contact Us</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="contactForm">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Learning_Contact::form.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 5) **app/code/Learning/Contact/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml**

```
<h1> Hi I'm here.... </h1>
```

Step 6) **cleared cache**

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Step 7) **enabled module**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Is above steps are correct or something went wrong?

Could you please throw me right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `app/code/Learning/Contact/view/frontend/layout/contact_index_index.xml` is wrong configured

Change this files to

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Contact Us</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="contactForm">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Learning_Contact::form.phtml</argument>
                </action>
         </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Just remove        `<referenceContainer name="content">` and         `</referenceContainer>` from your `contact_index_index.xml`

Don't forgot to clear cache

Comment: It's not mandatory to remove `<referenceContainer name="content">` and `</referenceContainer>` even I keep this I'm getting result. the problem with  cookie with chrome brower. It's working IE.

Answer (score 1):

In composer.json name should be

```
learning/module-contact
```

So, Change your **composer.json** following code

```
{
    "name": "learning/module-contact",
    "description": "contact",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-ui": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-config": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-contact": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "100.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Learning\\Contact\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

clear cache and run upgrade command again.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: `learning/module-contact` it's standard or mandatory? even my composer also working fine without modifying. however cookie problem in chrome browser.

Comment: This name field should be fully-qualified module name in the format <vendor-name>/module-<module-name>. It's mandatory.

Comment: For more information http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/package_module.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also set code in contact_index_index display below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Contact Us</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Krish_Contact::form.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```