# Overriding .phtml template

Tags: magento2, module, overrides

What is the recommended way to override the contact .phtml template. All I want to do is add HTML tags around the form so I can use bootstrap to give it a nice layout.

As far as I know there is no way to call the contact form in my contact-info page using something like `{{block class="..." template="..."}}`

So I tried to add the additional HTML code around the form in the .phtml thats being loaded on the contact page. What I've done is creating a form.phtml file in the path below as some answers on SO told me to:

`app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Contact/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml`

Besides that form.phtml the Magento_Contact folder is empty. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong file place :

`app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Contact/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml`

Should be

```
app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml
```

Comment: Additionally you need to redeploy static contents.

Comment: @S H Patel please clarify your answer according to this link http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html#theme-inherit-templates, you just gave a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think following thread can help you.

[Unable to overwrite Contact Form in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90831/unable-to-overwrite-contact-form-in-magento-2)

In this, sample module is used to achieve it.

Comment: That seems a little bit too much for only changing the form layout. The reason why my override didn't work is because I had the wrong path, see answer.